# public user id is received as the request through URL in retrofit?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, retrofit, retrofit2

im trying in get method in retrofit for Mysql database API " **public user id is received as the request through URL**" this my Request in API ..But I don't no how to get this Request any one help me   **this my Response**  {
"data": {
"number": "123456789"
},
"Status": "true",
"Message": ""
}

API: http://localhost/demo/api/publicUserNumber/13d02329ec856cb69e67a6263fc0cc87

How to create this retrofit in get method in android

**my main activity**

public UserRequestget getnu(){
SharedPreferences sp=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyUserPerfs",MODE_PRIVATE);
String phoneNumber=sp.getString("phonenum","");
String publicid=sp.getString("publicid","");

```
Log.e("registar application","phonenum...."+phoneNumber);
Log.e("registar application","publicid...."+publicid);
UserRequestget userRequestget=new UserRequestget();

return userRequestget;
```

}

```
private void getnum(UserRequestget getnu)  {
    SharedPreferences sp=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyUserPerfs",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String accesstoken=sp.getString("accesstoken","");
        String publicid=sp.getString("publicid","");
    Log.e("registar application","publicid...."+publicid);
    Log.e("registar application","accesstoken...."+accesstoken);

    Call<UserResponseAppget>userResponseAppgetCall=ApiClientApp.getuserServiceApp(accesstoken).getnumber1(getnu);
    userResponseAppgetCall.enqueue(new Callback<UserResponseAppget>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserResponseAppget> call, Response<UserResponseAppget> response) {
            UserResponseAppget userResponseAppget= response.body();

          phoneNumber.setText(userResponseAppget.getNumber());

            Log.e("phoneNumber", "onResponse: "+phoneNumber+userResponseAppget.getNumber() );
            Log.e("Registar application", "onResponse: "+userResponseAppget.getMessage() );
            Log.e("Registar application", "onResponse: "+userResponseAppget.getStatus() );

            if (userResponseAppget.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("true")){


            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), userResponseAppget.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }




        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserResponseAppget> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: phoneNumber: onResponse:null   Registar application: onResponse: No Data Found
    onResponse: false

Answer (score 0):

You APIInterface class should look like this.

```
@GET("/api/publicUserNumber/{Id}")
Call<ResponseBody> getList(@Path("Id") String userId)
```

This is called path parameter. And this will pass your user id in url :
http://localhost/demo/api/publicUserNumber/13d02329ec856cb69e67a6263fc0cc87

Please refer to the `path parameter` section of retrofit here - [Retrofit Path Parameter](https://howtodoinjava.com/retrofit2/query-path-parameters/)

Comment: interface ok but I don't no main class

Comment: Call<UserResponseAppget>userResponseAppgetCall=ApiClientApp.getuserServiceApp(accesstoken).getnumber("zczczzc");

Comment: To build from scratch refer to documentation or example https://guides.codepath.com/android/consuming-apis-with-retrofit

Comment: public void onResponse(Call<UserResponseAppget> call, Response<UserResponseAppget> response) {
                UserResponseAppget userResponseAppget= response.body();

              phoneNumber.setText(userResponseAppget.getNumber());

Comment: Log.e("phoneNumber", "onResponse: "+phoneNumber+userResponseAppget.getNumber() );
                Log.e("Registar application", "onResponse: "+userResponseAppget.getMessage() );
                Log.e("Registar application", "onResponse: "+userResponseAppget.getStatus() );